# Jsoup how to get values from html

Tags: java, html, jsoup

So I'm trying to get specific information from this link: https://myanimelist.net/anime/31988/Hibike_Euphonium_2

I don't really understand html so this is a bit harder for me.

I'm looking specifically get information from here:

```
<div>
    <span class="dark_text">Studios:</span>
          <a href="/anime/producer/2/Kyoto_Animation" title="Kyoto Animation">Kyoto Animation</a>  </div>

<div class="spaceit">
```

What I'm trying to do is search for when it says "Studios" and then get the title of the href link (Kyoto Animation).

So for I have managed to get this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://myanimelist.net/anime/31988/Hibike_Euphonium_2").get();

        Elements studio = doc.select("a[href][title]");
        for(Element link : studio){
            System.out.println(link.attr("title"));
        }
```

And it's outputting this:

```
Lantis
Pony Canyon
Rakuonsha
Ponycan USA
Kyoto Animation
Drama
Music
School
Kyoto Animation
Go to the Last Post
Go to the Last Post
Anime You Should Watch Before Their Sequels Air This Fall 2016 Season
Collection
Follow @myanimelist on Twitter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
doc.select("span:contains(Studios) + a[href][title]");
```

of I assume that `span` is common element for list header.

So basicly this selector gets all `span` elements that contains text `Studios` and then gets 1 level children `a` elements having attributes `href` and `title`

Just in case, given selector will select only one link and in `span`
More universal could be

```
*:contains(Studio) > a[title]
```

and that means - take every `a` element that has `title` attribute and is **direct children** of any (*) element that contains test `Studio`. Contains takes into account all text from descending children as well. For text of specific element `:textOwn` is used.

Comment: Ok that seems to make sense but if I try

Elements studio = doc.select("span:contains(Studios) > a[href][title]");
  for(Element link : studio){
   System.out.println(link.attr("title"));
  }

Nothing prints out.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but what about something like

```
    ...
    Elements studio = doc.select("a[@title='Kyoto Animations']");
    ...
```

Comment: The problem is if it's a different show on the website, it wouldn't necessarily be Kyoto Animation. "Studio:" is consist on other pages, so I want to find that, then pull the specific studio ie Kyoto Animation in this case.